# Cannot Connect to Dockerized Express HTTPS Server

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I'm trying to serve my app over HTTPS so that I can use a service worker with my React app.

To do this, I added https.createServer() to my Express startup script

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('robotapp:server');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8000');
app.set('port', port);
console.log('Listening on localhost:', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Add HTTPS server
 */

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod') {
    https
        .createServer(
            {
                key: fs.readFileSync('sslcerts/server.key', 'utf8'),
                cert: fs.readFileSync('sslcerts/server.pem', 'utf8')
            },
            app
        )
        .listen(443, function() {
            console.log('HTTPS listening on PORT 443');
        });
}

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

When I build the Docker container and start the app, both the HTTP and HTTPS server start up (I can see the "Listening on localhost:8000" and "HTTPS listening on PORT 443" messages). I can successfully access the HTTP version of my app on PORT 8000, but when I go to access PORT 443 on my server I get a "This site cannot be reached" error.

At first I thought maybe I mapped my container ports wrong, but I checked and nothing seems out of ordinary

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                          NAMES
16d0013eec8a        robotapp:2.1        "npm start"         4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   silly_tesla
```

If anyone has any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, please let me know :)

Comment: Could it be that you're binding to a port below 1024 w/o correct permissions? Try a higher port number, say 8443.

Comment: I tried 8001 before trying 443 and I got the same result

Comment: did you try reaching the port `443` using the container's IP? check the container's IP with `docker inspect container | grep -i ipaddress`

Comment: The HTTPS app should have the same IP as the HTTP app though since they are served from the same Express app in the same container? The only difference should be the port?